# Custom Operation with 5D Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'd like to extract from a 5D tensor, [batch, H, W, F, C], some slices of it and do some computation. In particular, I'm trying to extract for each position at a time of H and W all vectors F for each C.

It's a kind of convolution operation; I'm convolving the input, but for each position, I don't want to perform the convolution operation (kernel pointwise multiplication and sum).

Thanks

Comment: What are F and C in this case? I assume H and W are Height and Width?

Comment: F and C are other two dimensions of the input tensor. Let's say my input is [batch, 6, 6, 8, 10]. I'd like to take the first arrays in position 0 (H), 0 (W) with dimension 8 simultaneously from all 10 dimensions and make some computations. Then, doing that for  all remaining position H and W.